# set a fixed number of breaks in ggplot2 legend when plotting multiple plots

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, legend, break

Let's suppose I have a list `df` of 20 data.frames and I need to plot them in a `for loop` using `scale_fill_steps2`, as follows:

```
plot_lst=list()

for (i in 1:length(df)) {
  
    plot_lst[[i]] = ggplot() +
    geom_contour_fill(data=df[[i]], aes(x=lon, y=lat, z =value)) +
    scale_fill_steps2(name = "", low = "#0571b0", mid = '#ffffbf', high = '#ca0020')

}
```

Each of my data.frames has a different range of `value` and creating a taylored legend for each of them is not practical. By using the code above I get a legend with different number of breaks (or bins) between the data.frames.

Is there a way I can plot my data.frames with a unique number of breaks in the legend? e.g. 5 or 6 breaks in total.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Alternatively, rbind all the dataframes, then plot with a facet?

Comment: what is it facet? thanks

Comment: See https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html

Answer (score -1):

In your plotting function, use `seq()` to create a vector of length `numbreaks` based on the range of `value` for each data frame.

```
# plotting function
plotbreaks <- function(dat, numbreaks) {

    xmin <- min(dat$value)
    xmax <- max(dat$value)
   
    breaks <- seq(from = xmin, to = xmax,
                  by = round((xmax - xmin) / numbreaks, digits = 0))

    ggplot() +
    geom_contour_fill(data = dat,
                      mapping = aes(x = lon, y = lat, z = value)) +
    scale_fill_steps2(name = "", low = "#0571b0",
                      mid = "#ffffbf", high = "#ca0020",
                      breaks = breaks)

}

# loop through list of dataframes
for(i in 1:length(df)) {

  plotbreaks(dat = df[[i]],
             numbreaks = 5)

}
```

Comment: hi, thanks. the breaks parameter does not work

Comment: probably because I have values < 0 in my real data